# Android Studio 3.4 - Error transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForAwsDebug

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

Getting following error after upgrading to Android Studio 3.4

```
transformDexWithInstantRunSlicesApkForAwsDebug
```

Can someone explain what would be the possible case for above issue?

Comment: please add full error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling `Instant Run` by

Go to `Android Studio Settings or Preferences (for MAC) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Instant Run.`,

then uncheck "Enable Instant Run"

[image]

Comment: Yes. It worked but do you know why we are getting this error?

Comment: AFAIK, instant run is not perfect yet. When ever I see an error message contains `InstantRun`, I simply try turn it off and do it again. ;) You may find more information [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9on2ga/every_time_i_update_android_studio_something/)